# Callback allocates GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, keras, allocation

I have written a custom Callback (`BatchHistory`) for logging model performance per batch, rather than per epoch as the default History Callback does.

I am storing the BatchHistory objects as pickle files to later have access to the exact training history. I observe however that

1) the pickles of the Callback objects are 10 times as large as when I pickle only the `logs` field and

2) when unpickling a BatchHistory object, GPU memory is being allocated.

I don't understand why that is. I have looked into the [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L148) for Callbacks and these are basically plain classes with no logic tied to keras models. So where is the GPU memory allocation coming from and why are the pickle files so big, independent of the actual logged data? There must be some data from the model that was trained with the callback tied to the Callback object that gets pickled with it, causing the large pickle files. Is that the case? If so: why and where is in the source is the responsible code.

This is an OOM error I get when unpickling a Callback when the GPU is already in use heavy:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/neucores/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/neucores/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

~/anaconda3/envs/neucores/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8704,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training/Adam/Variable_30/Assign}} = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _grappler_relax_allocator_constraints=true, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/Adam/Variable_30, training/Adam/zeros_12)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

And this is my Callback class. But I don't think my code has anything to do with his. It must be about the base class. But as I said, in the source I cannot find anything either that might cause GPU memory allocation.

```
class BatchHistory(Callback):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.logs =  {'loss' : [],
                      'acc' : [],
                      'val_acc' : [],
                      'val_loss' : [],
                      'epoch_cnt' : 0,
                      'epoch_ends' : [],
                      'time_elapsed' : 0 # seconds
                     }
        self.start_time = time.time() 

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        pass

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.logs['acc'].append(logs.get('acc'))
        self.logs['loss'].append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.logs['time_elapsed']=int(time.time()-self.start_time)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epochs, logs=None):
        self.logs['epoch_cnt']+=1
        self.logs['epoch_ends'].append(len(self.logs['loss']))
        self.logs['val_acc'].append(logs.get('val_acc'))
        self.logs['val_loss'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))
```